# How to integrate Android Git project API?

Tags: android, git

I am trying to integrate this Git project
https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-contact-extractor

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.coderconsole.cextracter:contact-extractor:1.0.0'
}
```

For the above, do i have to extract the whole com.coderconsole.cextracter to my project in order for dependencies to recognize?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

I know this is needed. But Why does the original Git project don't even have this in the manifest?

I am totally new to Android development. So how do I integrate and use the Git API? And what I need is a Access contact list button whereby it would require permission from user before dumping the result into console log or a simple `printf` statement (they called it 'toast' right?)

Comment: Its gradle dependency which you have to just copy paste in your module's build.gradle folder to access the library.A sample project and library both are pushed to git repository. If found any issue in the library do share into the issues section.

Comment: To clarify its not the git api its an library which is pushed to github repository. I recommed you to create a android studio project and integrate the library as mentioned in the readme section https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-contact-extractor